# Server Error in Application - when trying to access WCF Service

Tags: wcf, iis-7, wcf-hosting

I have a WCF service that I would like to host in IIS 7.5. My setup:
The physical path of the folder with .svc file is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SmartSolution\Services\Services\ContainerManagementService.svc
My binaries are in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SmartSolution\Services\bin and I also copied them to 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SmartSolution\Services\Services\bin

I have created a web application in IIS for both Services folders.

Here is the config file for the WCF endpoint:

```
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementServiceBehavior"
    name="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       name="ContainerManagementbasicHttpEndpoint" contract="MyNamespace.IContainer"/>                  
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>      
   <behaviors>      
    <behavior name="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
</behaviors>
```

Here is my .svc file makrkup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyNamespace.ContainerManagementService" CodeBehind="ContainerManagementService.svc.cs" %>
```

When I try to navigate to: http://localhost/SmartSolution/Services/Services/ContainerManagementService.svc , the following error is displayed:

> Server Error in
>   '/SMARTSOLUTION/Services/Services'
>   Application.
>   [ServiceActivationException: The
>   service
>   '/SMARTSOLUTION/Services/Services/ContainerManagementService.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is:  is not a valid
>   Win32 application. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x800700C1).] is not a valid
>   Win32 application. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

How can I get the service to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the exceptions, it seems that your assemblies (in bin folder) are built targeting x64 Plaform and they're now either deployed on 32bit machine or application pool configured for application is running under 32bit mode (Enable 32 bit Applications = "true"). Thus, process is unable to load the assemblies built for x64 platform and fails with exception.

HTH
Amit

Comment: The actual fix was this: 1. Inside IIS (7) click on Application Pools.

2. Find the Application Pool that is configured for your web application in the list.

3. Select it, then click Advanced Settings on the right.

4. Second setting in the list: Enable 32-Bit Applications - must be set to True.